# ClassNotFoundException Symfony2 Validator

Tags: class, validation, symfony, exception

So I have this custom validator in Symfony2.4,

```
namespace My\Bundle\validation\Constraints;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
/**
* @Annotation
*/
class CustomValidator extends Constraint {
/**
* @var str the message to display if violation
*/
public $message = "the message";

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validatedBy()
{
return 'my_validator_service';      
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getTargets()
{
return self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT;
}
}
```

Now, in a different bundle FormType:

```
.....
use My\Bundle\Validation\Constraints;

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{

 $collectionConstraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
 .......,
 'test' => array(
    new CustomValidator(),
),
 ........

 $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'constraints' => $collectionConstraint,
        'data' => $data,
    ));
}
```

But I got this exception:

ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "CustomValidator" from namespace "My\Bundle\Validation\Constraints" in blabla\Type. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

What do you think? Probably is is something trivial but I don't know what it could be

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found it.
namespace and use was correct, but the folderwas called Validator instead of Validation.
Sorry all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your use directive in:

```
use My\Bundle\Validation\Constraints\CustomValidator;
```

Comment: I already tried various combinations, using `as`, or different names. But with no result.